# Repository pattern and Entity Framework Include

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm using the repository pattern with EF, and I think I'm pretty much sold on it but one question remains;

If I want to eager load an entity, what is the best way to do this?

For example, I have a repository mapped to an entity:

```
public class EFFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
     public IQueryable<Foo> GetFoo()
     {
        .....
     }
}
```

What if I want to get Foo and Bar objects

```
db.Foo.Include("Bar")
```

But my repository only returns Foo, so do I need to create another method GetFooAndBar?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled lazyloading you can load the `Bar` later (When you are going to access the property) . But if you want to write a method which loads the data `Foo` with `Bar` at the same time yes you need to write specific repository methods.

Comment: _you can load the Bar later_... That depends. The context must still be alive then.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same. When I implement the Repository pattern I wanted to be able to use the IQueryable< T > and IEnumerable< T > that the DbSet< T > implements offered, without exposing the DbSet < T > (good old information hiding)

Therefore I thought it would be enough to let all IQueryable / IEnumerable functions call the corresponding function of the DbSet< T > in the Repository.

Until today that was enough for all my IQueryable< T > functions. Today I discovered that except IQueryable.Include had the same problem you described. There is no compiler error, but the data is not loaded.

After extensive result I found that the reason is described in the MSDN description of [QueryableExtensions.Include Method (IQueryable, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.include(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include%60%602(System.Linq.IQueryable%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D))

> This extension method calls the Include(String) method of the source IQueryable object, if such a method exists. **If the source IQueryable does not have a matching method, then this method does nothing.**

So all I had to do was to write a matching include statement in my repository that would call the corresponding DbSet repository. The IQueryable / IEnumerable functions simply call the corresponding functions of the DbSet:

```
public class Repository<T> : 
    System.Linq.IQueryable<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>,
    System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Collections.IEnumerable
    where T : class, new()
{
    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public virtual DbQuery<T> Include(string path)
    {
        return this.dbSet.Include(path);
    }

    // other Repository functions: Find / Add / Update / Remove etc
```

For completeness the IQueryable / IEnumerable implementaiton:

```
    #region IQueryable
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IQueryable<T>)this.dbSet).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)this.dbSet).GetEnumerator();
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return ((IQueryable<T>)this.dbSet).ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return ((IQueryable)this.dbSet).Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return ((IQueryable)this.dbSet).Provider; }
    }
    #endregion IQueryable
```

Now the following works, the Address is included:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    Repository<Customer> customers = new Repository<Customer>(dbContext);
    var happyCustomers = customers
        .Include(customer => customer.Address)
        .Where(customer => customer.IsHappy);
    Show(happyCustomers);
}
```

Comment: Hope there is no other QueryableExtension function that does nothing if the function if not present